# VariableSizedWrapGrid and WrapGrid children size measuring

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

Both `VariableSizedWrapGrid` and `WrapGrid` have strange measuring - they measure all children based on the first item.

Because of that, the following XAML will clip the third item.

```
    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="100" Margin="5" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Margin="5" Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="150" Margin="5" Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" Margin="5" Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="100" Margin="5" Fill="Red" />
    </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
```

Seems like `VariableSizedWrapGrid` measures the first item and then the rest children are measured with desired size of the first one.

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Attached Properties on each Rectangle VariableSizeWrapGrid.ColumnSpan and VariableSizeWrapGrid.RowSpan as well as add an ItemHeight and ItemWidth to the VariableSizeWrapGrid:

```
<VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" ItemHeight="50" ItemWidth="50"> 
    <Rectangle 
        VariableSizedWrapGrid.ColumnSpan="1" 
        VariableSizedWrapGrid.RowSpan="2"
        Width="50" Height="100" Margin="5" Fill="Blue" /> 
</VariableSizedWrapGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its may be not the best way but this is how I have done this in my @MetroRSSReader app

```
<common:VariableGridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid ItemWidth="225" 
                                           ItemHeight="{Binding ElementName=bounds, Path=Text}" 
                                           MaximumRowsOrColumns="5" Orientation="Vertical"
                                           />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </common:VariableGridView.ItemsPanel>
        </common:VariableGridView>
```

Notice the ItemHeight value is bound to a TextBlock

```
<TextBlock x:Name="bounds" Grid.Row="1" Margin="316,8,0,33" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Which is set in the LayoutAwarePage.cs

```
public string Fix_item_height_for_current_screen_resolution()
    {
        var screenheight = CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Bounds.Height;
        var itemHeight = screenheight < 1000 ? "100" : "140";

        return itemHeight;
    }
```

You can browse the full source code http://metrorssreader.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/18233#265970

Answer (score 0):

To use a VariableSizeWrapGrid you should create your own GridView custom control and override `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` and set the elements RowSpan and ColumnSpan inside that method. That way each element will have its own height/width.

Here is a nice tutorial/walk through by Jerry Nixon : http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/windows-8-beauty-tip-using

Comment: Any idea how one could add such the row/col spans get databound and updated when the model changes. PrepareContainerForItemOverride  is not called on changes.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this one out today. You'll need to make use of VisualTreeHelperExtension.cs in the WinRT XAML Toolkit (http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com). For me I was trying to adjust a ListView that had a GridView as its ItemsPanelTemplate, the same concept should apply for you.

1) Attach to the LayoutUpdated event of your ListView (this is when you'll want to update the sizes)

> `_myList.LayoutUpdated += _myList_LayoutUpdated;`

2) Use VisualTreeHelperExtensions.GetDescendantsOfType() to find a common (and unique) element type in your item's data template (ex: a TextBlock that is dynamic in width):

> ```
> var items = VisualTreeHelperExtensions.GetDescendantsOfType<TextBlock>(_myList);  
>
> if (items == null || items.Count() == 0)
>   return;
> ```

3) Get the max width of the items found:

> `double maxWidth = items.Max(i => i.ActualWidth) + 8;`

4) Use VisualTreeHelperExtensions.GetDescendantsOfType() to find the main WrapGrid container for your ListView:

> ```
> var wg = _categoryList.GetDescendantsOfType<WrapGrid>();
> if (wg == null || wg.Count() != 1)
>   throw new InvalidOperationException("Couldn't find main ListView container");
> ```

5) Set the WrapGrid's ItemWidth to the maxWidth you calculated:

> `wg.First().ItemWidth = maxWidth;`